# Точка или вопросительный знак?

Tags: пунктуация

> Господи, ну почему меня встретили именно они.

Интонация вопросительная, но тут можно поставить точку, верно? Но почему?

Answer (score 3):

Вопросительная интонация должна обозначаться вопросительным знаком. В правилах говорится, что вопросительный знак ставится даже  в конце **риторического вопроса.**  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

Можно дополнительно поставить восклицательный знак, если здесь выражены эмоции, но точку ставить нельзя:

**Господи, ну почему меня встретили именно они?!**

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, интонация не позволяет поставить точку. А вот восклицательный знак или два знака вместе возможны, так как вопрос риторический, не требующий ответа, то есть по сути это восклицание.

> Иду, повторяю: "Господи! Господи! За что мне такое наказание?!" И сам же думаю: "Как за что? [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)]

-

> В зависимости от оттенка значения и от интонации некоторые предложения допускают постановку в конце их вопросительного или восклицательного знака либо того и другого вместе:
>
> А погода будет ожидать вас?! А если дождь пойдет?! ...Где Любишкин, спрашиваю?! (М. Шолохов).
>
> А погода будет ожидать вас? А если дождь пойдёт? ...Где Любишкин, спрашиваю?
>
> А погода будет ожидать вас! А если дождь пойдет! ...Где Любишкин, спрашиваю!

(http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/vosklitsatelnyiy-znak-70972.html)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что здесь обязателен *вопросительный* знак, поскольку есть обращение (Господи) и побуждающая к ответу частица "ну". С точкой возможен такой вариант:

> Интересно/любопытно, почему меня встретили именно они.

Comment: Здесь "господи" вряд ли можно считать обращением. Скорее, междометие. См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8&all=x

Comment: Это зависит от степени веры и от того, кто и где встретил: возможно, вместо Архангела Михаила у соотв. врат, грешника встретили не те и не там :) Междометие же есть "поминание всуе" имени Господа.